# Как отправлять json post-запросы на сервер на .Net Framework Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7, silverlight

Мне нужно создать приложение для Windows Phone 7. Для этого я использовал Windows Phone 7 SDK с *Visual Studio 2010* в нём.
В этом приложении мне нужно отправлять json post-запросы на сервер. Для сего дела я использовал вот этот гайд
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Window...
Ибо стандартные методы у меня отсутствовали.

Я решил использовать оба метода с `webclient` и `httpwebrequest`. Для начала мне нужно было отправить данные вводимые пользователем для авторизации и получать в виде данных пользователя и его ключ для выполнения других запросов.

Данные сервер требовал в виде : "Метод, ключ пользователя, параметры", а отвечал в виде статуса запроса ("ОК" или "Ошибка") и прочие параметры.

Для работы с Json-ом я использовал стороннюю библиотеку от Newtonsoft
В итоге у меня получилось вот что.

```
public static class Method
{
    static object root = null;
    static string Login = null;
    static string Pass = null;

    private static void Wbc_UploadCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
        {
            try
            {
                root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public static AuthorizedAnswer Authorizewbc(string login, string pass)
    {
        Uri URI = new Uri("http://bistrodrive.azurewebsites.net/api`");
        Request req = new Request();
        req.Method = "login";
        req.Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        req.Parameters.Add("login", login);
        req.Parameters.Add("password", pass);
        string myParameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        //wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
        wc.Headers["X-Accept"] = "application/json";
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += Wbc_UploadCompleted;
        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", myParameters);
        while (root == null) {    }
        return root as AuthorizedAnswer;

    }
    public static AuthorizedAnswer Authorizewbr(string login, string pass)
    {
        Login = login;
        Pass = pass;
        string AuthServiceUri = "http://bistrodrive.azurewebsites.net/api";
        HttpWebRequest spAuthReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(AuthServiceUri) as HttpWebRequest;
        spAuthReq.ContentType = "application/json";
        spAuthReq.Method = "POST";
        spAuthReq.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), spAuthReq);
        spAuthReq.Headers["X-Accept"] = "application/json";
        while (root == null) { }
        return root as AuthorizedAnswer;
    }
    static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        Request req = new Request();
        Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
        req.Method = "login";
        req.Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        req.Parameters.Add("login", Login);
        req.Parameters.Add("password", Pass);
        string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
    }
    static void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
            string responseString = "";
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            streamResponse.Close();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            string result = responseString;
            root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
public class AuthorizedAnswer
{
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public List<String> Result { get; set; }
}
public class Request
{    
    public string Method { set; get; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Parameters { set; get; }
    public string Token { set; get; }
}
}
```

В результате сервер просто не отправлял ответ. Почему - понятия не имею.

Comment: Установлен ли у вас *Advanced REST client* в браузере? попробуйте обратится к серверу через него

Comment: Но мне нужно именно через эмулятор.

Comment: я понимаю что вам надо через эмулятор, но вы сперва отладте запрос через REST client, посмотрите как он работает, а потом уже отправляйте через эмулятор. Надо принимать сервер как заведомо отлаженный механизм, ведь если сервер вам не отвечает это проблема не сервера, так? а неправильно сформированного запроса

Comment: Отправлял запросы через эту программу. В принципе, ответы всегда приходят. В виде ответа об ошибке или правильного, но это ответы сервера. А вот в программе такого не происходит.

Comment: В методе `Authorizewbc(string login, string pass)` у вас лишний сивол в URL, попробуйте избавится от него

Comment: Уже избавился, ничего не поменялось.